# Displaying Null Fields

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to display beds that are empty by filling in the filed with "Empty Bed". Currently only the beds assigned with patients are rendering on the report. See below for my formula

`if isnull({pat_view.pat_room}) = true then "Empty Bed"`

Im getting an error saying that "the remaining text does not to appear to be part of  the formula".

Comment: The formula is correct and does work in Crystal Reports when "Crystal syntax" is set in formular editor. Could the error be caused by a different part of the report?

Comment: @mweber hmmm, im not to sure, with me setting the Report to above formula it now displays 'The result of selection Formula must be a boolean. Does this mean instead of "empty bed" it needs to be either true or false?

Comment: @mweber hmm it only works with statements true or false, is there a way to bybass this and input a string instead of a bolean? or will i need to find a different table to represent "empty bed"

Comment: I thought the formula was content of a "formula field" – as you'll need a "formula field" to display the result within the report. The error message you mentioned shows that you're trying with a "selection formula", which is used to control which records are processed by the report (and therefore has to have a boolean result). So just create a new formula field with the above formula, and drag that into the report.

Comment: @mweber ahh thank you! i also had the wrong syntax lol. it require ' ' not " ". Thank you!